# debugging high response time in python flask

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, newrelic

I have logs regarding response times in `aws`

[image: aws graphs]

[image: new relic]

how can I further debug this? I thought it was the mongodb connection time. how to debug python high response time?

Comment: There is a known issue about `flask-security` which will significantly slow down response with token-authorization. Maybe you are suffering the same issue?

Comment: @Sraw not using `flask-security`